# How would you structure data with different datatypes in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Right now I have many locations with this structure. At the moment I have: name as `string` and x,y,z positions as `single`. So it's a mix of data types and I might want to add both more data in the future and also other data types. I must be able to easily extract any part of this data.

Example of how I'll work with this data is: When I choose South Wales from a combobox then I want to get its properties, x,y,z populated in a textbox. So they need to be "linked". If I choose London then it'll have its x,y,z properties etc.

My initial idea is just to `dim` every single data such as in the first example below. This should be the easiest way with 100% control of what's what, and I could easily extract any single data but at the same time might get tedious I assume, or am I wrong? Is it a good way to approach this?

```
    Dim SW_FP As String = "South Wales"
    Dim SW_FP_X As Single = "489,1154"
    Dim SW_FP_Y As Single = "-8836,795"
    Dim SW_FP_Z As Single = "109,6124"
```

The next example below is something i just googled up. Is this a good method?

```
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("South Wales", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("489,1154", GetType(Single))
    dt.Columns.Add("-8836,795", GetType(Single))
    dt.Columns.Add("109,6124", GetType(Single))
```

OR should I use something else? Arrays, Objects with properties... and this is where my ideas end. Are there other methods? XML?

I want to do it in a smart way from start instead of risking to rewrite/recreate everything in the future. So my main question is: **Which method would you suggest to be the smartest to choose?** and also if you could provide a super tiny code example.

Comment: Do you have the option of using a database for this project?

Comment: Yes I have this option, I'm not ruling out anything.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned that when you choose an item you want to get it's properties. This shows that you are looking for objects. If not using a database one example could be to make `Location` objects and have a `List` of these to be added or removed from. Then you have a lot of different ways to get the data back from the `List`. For example:

Class:

```
Public Class Location
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property X As Single
    Public Property Y As Single
    Public Property Z As Single
End Class
```

List:

```
Dim locations As New List(Of Location)
Dim location As New Location With {
    .Name = "South Wales",
    .X = 1.1,
    .Y = 1.2,
    .Z = 1.3
}
locations.Add(location)
```

LINQ to get result:

```
Dim result = locations.SingleOrDefault(Function(i) i.Name = "South Wales")
```

This is just an example for use within your program, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer: Untested code. It's more to guide you than copy-paste into your project.**

First, create a Class that will represent the structured data:

```
Public Class Location

    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property PositionX As Single
    Public Property PositionY As Single
    Public Property PositionZ As Single

    Public Sub New()
        Me.New (String.Empty, 0, 0, 0)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(name As String, x As Single, y As Single, z As Single)
        Me.Name = name
        Me.PositionX = x
        Me.PositionY = y
        Me.PositionZ = z
    End Sub
```

Now, you can create a `List(Of Location)` and use that List to bind to a ComboBox, like this:

```
Dim list As New List(Of Location) = someOtherClass.ReadLocations ' Returns a List(Of Location) from your database, or file, or whatever.

cboLocations.DataSource = list
cboLocations.DisplayMember = "Name" ' The name of the Location class' Property to display.
cboLocations.ValueMember = "Name" ' Use the same Name Property since you have no ID.
```

You can also forego the `list` variable declaration like the following, but I wanted to show the declaration of `list` above:

```
cboLocations.DataSource = someOtherClass.ReadLocations
```

Function `someOtherClass.ReadLocations()` may populate the List(Of Locations) in a way similar to this. Note I'm not including data access code; this is just an example to show how to add Location objects to the List(Of Location):

```
Dim list As List(Of Location)

' Some loop construct
For each foo in Bar

    Dim item As New Location(foo.Name, foo.X, foo.Y, foo.Z)
    list.Add(item)

' End loop

Return list
```

The "magic" happens when you select an option from the ComboBox. I forget the ComboBox event offhand, so that's homework for you :-) You take the selected Object of the ComboBox and cast it back to the native type, in this case `Location`:

```
Dim item As Location = DirectCast(cboLocations.SelectedItem, Location)

txtName.Text = item.Name
txtPosX.Text = item.PositionX.ToString
txtPosY.Text = item.PositionY.ToString
txtPosZ.Text = item.PositionZ.ToString
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way, using a DataTable as you mentioned. This is a stand alone example project just to show code used.
This example loads data from file is found and saves data on exit.
[Form1 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOk3N.png)

```
' Stand alone example
' needs DataGridView1, Label1 and
' ComboBox1 on the Designer
' copy/replace this code with default

Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Public Class Form1
    Dim dt As New DataTable("Freddy")
    Dim bs As New BindingSource

    'edit path/filename to use as test data path
    Dim filepath As String = "C:\Users\lesha\Desktop\TestData.xml"
    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        dt.WriteXml(filepath)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        With dt
            dt.Columns.Add("Country", GetType(String))
            dt.Columns.Add("x", GetType(String))
            dt.Columns.Add("y", GetType(String))
            dt.Columns.Add("z", GetType(String))

            ' add extra column to hold concatenated
            ' location  (could be a hidden column)
            dt.Columns.Add("CombLoc", GetType(String), "'x = ' + x  + '  y = '  +  y + '  z = ' + z")

            If IO.File.Exists(filepath) Then
                ' saved file found so load it
                dt.ReadXml(filepath)
            Else
                ' no saved file so make one test row
                .Rows.Add("South Wales", 489.1154, -8836.795, 109.6124)
            End If
        End With
        bs.DataSource = dt
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bs

        ' set any properties for DataGridView1
        With DataGridView1
            ' to hide Combined Location column
            .Columns("CombLoc").Visible = False
            ' dontwant row headers
            .RowHeadersVisible = False
        End With

        set up ComboBox
        With ComboBox1
            .DataSource = bs
            ' displayed item
            .DisplayMember = "Country"
            ' returned item 
            .ValueMember = "CombLoc"
            If .Items.Count > 0 Then .SelectedIndex = 0
        End With

        ' default Label text
        Label1.Text = "No items found"
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        no items in list so exit sub
        If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex < 0 Then Exit Sub
        send returneditem to Label
        Label1.Text = ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString
    End Sub
End Class
```